# Notifications System idea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, redis, rails-postgresql

I am trying to integrate a notifications system into one of my rails apps. I am using `PostgreSQL` as my primary database. I am considering to use `redis` for supporting the notifications system. 
However, I have some questions regarding the usage of redis:

1. Handling different types of notifications(Eg.: User commented on post, liked post, tagged in a photo etc).
2. If I have a namespaced key in redis for notifications per user, how to manage the load, meaning setting the limit of number of notifications.
3. Store notifications as a string or use hash(Eg.: User A commented on User B's post)
4. A PubSub feature for notifying all other users as well(Eg.: If User A comments on a post, all users who commented/liked a post must be notified).

Any ideas how this kind of notification system must be designed?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am just asking for suggestions and how redis can really be used to implement such kind of a system, as I have now prior experience on redis.

Comment: Well, there's plenty of info in the internet. You can get some ideas from there: [using+redis+for+notification+system](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+redis+for+notification+system&oq=using+redis+for+notification+system&aqs=chrome..69i57.4605j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)